# How to submit some or All controls in an ASPX page using HTTP post

Tags: javascript, asp.net, httpwebrequest, http-post, imageurl

I have an aspx page named ShowDesign.aspx and it is browsed using URL `myurl.com/showdesign.aspx?id=420420`

The aspx page has many controls such as image, text button, radio buttons etc. Some of the controls are created in code-behind and the values to most of the controls are assigned/updated in code-behind.

When the page is ready to be displayed, I would like to use HTTP Post on some the controls (otherwise use HTTP post for entire page). I have not done this and would like to know how to do it? What code should I add and where should I add in the code-behind?

**Update**
Want to know the below Javascript will do what I am looking for? I am still checking it. If anyone has any feedback, please update.

```
function postToURL(url, values) {
    values = values || {};

    var form = createElement("form", {action: url,
                                      method: "POST",
                                      style: "display: none"});
    for (var property in values) {
        if (values.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            var value = values[property];
            if (value instanceof Array) {
                for (var i = 0, l = value.length; i < l; i++) {
                    form.appendChild(createElement("input", {type: "hidden",
                                                             name: property,
                                                             value: value[i]}));
                }
            }
            else {
                form.appendChild(createElement("input", {type: "hidden",
                                                         name: property,
                                                         value: value}));
            }
        }
    }
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
    document.body.removeChild(form);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for.  You just want to post your form and process your data from just certain fields while ignoring others?

Comment: Yes. I want the URL to be displayed only after HTTP post is done. I need to do this for some controls in the page.

Comment: Ok you lost me even more.  What does displaying the URL have to do with running and code on your objects?

Comment: @Limey : Let me clarify. I meant URL by the ASPX page.  All I need to do before the page gets displayed, I want to do Http Post on all controls in the page and then display it.

Comment: So you just need to know how to process the data that was submitted?

Comment: @Limey: Yes before page is displayed, I want to do http POST on certain controls and then allow page to be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what your looking for:

http://www.stardeveloper.com/articles/display.html?article=2003061901&page=1

Comment: I don't want to submit to another page. The page in my example ShowDesign.aspx is what needs to be displayed using Http Post.

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question.  You are either looking for something that is either really basic or really complex.  Either way, I have no clue of knowing till there is clarification.

Comment: Let me clarify. I have an imageControl which gets assigned with URL in code-behind. The length of this URL is around 2000 characters. When page is displayed, this image doesn't get displayed. So I want to submit the page with http post hoping that the image gets displayed as I understand that http post will handle the issue I am facing. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You are storing the image information in the URL? if not, why is it so long, cause that is getting near (or surpasing) how long of a URL some browsers will accept.